# Saber el nombre de determinadas columnas mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo un programa en java y necesito saber el nombre de las columnas de mi base de datos que corresponden a #2 hasta #11 porque el resto de columnas no las necesito, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Sé como sacar todas las columnas, pero no solo desde la segunda posición hasta la onceaba (tengo 17 columnas).

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El schema information_schema tiene todo lo que quiere.

Intente este:

```
Use Information_schema;
Select column_name from columns where table_schema = 'nombre_base_de_datos' and table_name = 'nombre_de_la_tabla' and ordinal_position >= 2 and ordinal_position <= 11 order by ordinal_position;
```

Comment: ¡Funciona, muchas gracias!